# How to import module as a Python dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python module with some variable definition, like this
(content of file `some_string.py`):

```
STRING1 = "STRING1"
STRING2 = "STRING2"
STRING3 = "STRING3"
STRING4 = "STRING4"
```

I know I can import it simply this way:

```
import some_string as sm
```

But I'm wonderig if there is a (as simple as possible) way to import it as dictionary. To explain what I mean: I would like to get a dictionary `sm` something like this:

```
{"STRING1": "STRING1",
 "STRING2": "STRING2",
 "STRING3": "STRING3",
 "STRING4": "STRING4"}
```

Is this possible to achieve this starting from "`some_string.py`"? (Possibly in Python 3.x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function like this:

```
import some_string as s

my_dict = {}
for val in dir(s):
    if not val.startswith("__"):
        my_dict[val] = getattr(s, val)
```

and your dict is ready to use!

EDIT: fix spelling

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for!